# get confusion on token

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been working on user token to send specific push notification to that users. Here are two tokens I create to put into firebase.

```
public void getDeviceToken(){
        FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String device_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        String msg = getString(R.string.fcm_token, device_token);
        Log.d("device_token", msg); //first one [dfw-A....]

        mUser.getIdToken(true)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                            String uid = m_auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                            Log.d("device_token2", idToken); //second one [eyJh...]
                            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
                            DatabaseReference id = ref.child(uid);
                            id.child("token").setValue(idToken);
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Main_Err", "token" , task.getException());
                            // Handle error -> task.getException();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

I want to know if I want to use user token to push notification, which one should I use? [1/ or 2]

Answer (score 0):

For sending notifications using Firebase Cloud Messaging, you should be using the device ID token from `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`.  The other user ID token from Firebase Authentication is not going to help you at all with messaging.

Please see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token) for more specific and thorough examples.

Answer (score 0):

use `String device_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();`

to send notifications to users, this token is specially for FCM